# fatal error: SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, sdl, sdl-2

i'm trying to run a C game i found on youtube using CLion but i keep getting this error: `fatal error: SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h: No such file or directory`. i downloaded the SDL2_gfx library but seems like there's something wrong with the CMakeList.txt that can't find the file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(untitled C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR C:/SDL2/include)
set(SDL2_LIB_DIR C:/SDL2/lib/x86)
set(SDL2_GFX C:/SDL2_gfx)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${SDL2_LIB_DIR})

find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(SDL2_GFX SDL2_gfx)
include_directories(${SDL2_GFX_INCLUDE_DIRS})

SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O0 -Wall -Werror -fdump-rtl-expand")

# add_executable(untitled main.c)

set(SRCS
        main.c
        logic.c
        rendering.c
        )

set(HEADERS
        logic.h
        rendering.h
        game.h
        )

add_executable(untitled ${SRCS} ${HEADERS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} SDL2main SDL2 ${SDL2_GFX_LIBRARIES})
```

If someone knows how to fix it, thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you show the CMake output and the contents of `${SDL2_GFX_INCLUDE_DIRS}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not provide many importing bits of information, like the OS and Minimum Reproducible Example, but I'll to help you anyway.

If you use Linux, you need to install the sdl2_gfx package.

[image: sdl2_gfx in Manjaro Linux package manager]

> /usr/include/SDL2/SDL2_framerate.h
> **/usr/include/SDL2/SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h**
> /usr/include/SDL2/SDL2_imageFilter.h /usr/include/SDL2/SDL2_rotozoom.h
> /usr/lib/libSDL2_gfx-1.0.so.0 /usr/lib/libSDL2_gfx-1.0.so.0.0.2
> /usr/lib/libSDL2_gfx.so /usr/lib/pkgconfig/SDL2_gfx.pc
> /usr/share/licenses/sdl2_gfx/LICENSE